# Using a Group BY or PARTITION on multiple columns where records are grouped together if ANY of the columns return a match

Tags: sql, group-by, common-table-expression, greenplum

Let's say I have the following table:

```
Record_ID | Match_criteria_1 |  Match_criteria_2  | Match_criteria_3 | Dollars  

     1    |  A               |   V                |   F              |   10  
     2    |  A               |   W                |   G              |   20  
     3    |  B               |   W                |   H              |   30  
     4    |  B               |   X                |   I              |   40  
     5    |  C               |   Y                |   F              |   50  
     6    |  C               |   Z                |   J              |   60
```

If I try to use a 'GROUP BY' or 'Over (PARTITION BY)' on Match_criteria_1, Match_criteria_2, and Match_criteria_3, I would end up with separate 6 groups/partitions.

```
   SELECT *, sum(Dollars) OVER (PARTITION BY Match_criteria_1, Match_criteria_2, Match_Criteria_3) AS Total_Dollars 
   FROM My_table
```

---

```
Record_ID | Match_criteria_1 |  Match_criteria_2  | Match_criteria_3 | Dollars     | Total_Dollars 

     1    |  A               |   V                |   F              |   10        | 10 
     2    |  A               |   W                |   G              |   20        | 20 
     3    |  B               |   W                |   H              |   30        | 30  
     4    |  B               |   X                |   I              |   40        | 40 
     5    |  C               |   Y                |   F              |   50        | 50
     6    |  C               |   Z                |   J              |   60        | 60
```

As you can see, none of the records have the same Match_criteria_1, Match_criteria_2, and Match_criteria_3.

But what if I wanted to group records that have the same Match_criteria_1, Match_criteria_2 **OR** Match_criteria_3?

So using my example, Record 1 matches with Record 2 due to Match_criteria_1, Record 2 matches with Record 3 due to Match_criteria_2, Record 3 matches with Record 4 due to Match_criteria_1, Record 5 matches with Record 1 due to Match_Criteria_3, and Record 6 matches with Record 5 due to Match_criteria 1 (so sort of a transitive property thing going on). The desired result then is :

```
Record_ID | Match_criteria_1 |  Match_criteria_2  | Match_criteria_3 | Dollars     | Total_Dollars 

     1    |  A               |   V                |   F              |   10        | 210 
     2    |  A               |   W                |   G              |   20        | 210 
     3    |  B               |   W                |   H              |   30        | 210  
     4    |  B               |   X                |   I              |   40        | 210 
     5    |  C               |   Y                |   F              |   50        | 210
     6    |  C               |   Z                |   J              |   60        | 210
```

where Total_dollars is the sum of every record due to the fact that all six policies match with each other due to transitivity. So Records 1 and 6 may have no match criteria in common but they are still grouped together because they both match with Record 5.

Comment: I'm confused about where you think I made a mistake. Record 1 matches with Record 2 due to MC1 (they both have 'A'). Record 1 also matches with Record 5 due to MC3 (they both have 'F'). Record 1 doesn't *directly* match with anything else but through transitivity it ends up matching with every record.

Comment: Greenplum or Postgres? They are sufficiently different that it doesn't make sense to add both tags

Comment: To be honest I'm not too sure. It's definitely a Greenplum database but I was under the impression that Greenplum DBs used Postgres as the dialect.

Comment: How about you provide the expected output?

Comment: @JonRoberts I already did. The expected output is the last table in my question (desired result)

Comment: @Vincent_Adultman . . . You would need a recursive CTE to do what you want.  Are you using the most recent version?  I'm looking at the documentation at https://gpdb.docs.pivotal.io/570/admin_guide/query/topics/CTE-query.html.

Comment: Yes that's the version I'm using!

Comment: Sounds like a painful recursive CTE where you have to account for relationship chains that link back to themselves (loop/circular).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I am understanding this incorrectly, but I think you could just get the total dollars for all rows that match other rows and join to that?  I'm not sure exactly what your expected output should be if a row doesn't match.  This answer will still include that row, but the total dollars would not include the amount in that row.

```
SELECT test.*, total_dollars 
FROM test, 
    (SELECT sum(dollars) as total_dollars 
     FROM (select distinct test.* FROM test
     JOIN test test2 ON (ARRAY[test.match_criteria_1, test.match_criteria_2, test.match_criteria_3] && ARRAY[test2.match_criteria_1, test2.match_criteria_2, test2.match_criteria_3])
     AND test.record_id != test2.record_id order by 1
    ) sub)
sub2;
```

I added another row that shouldn't match any of the others:
insert into test VALUES (7, 'M', 'N', 'O', 100);

and here are the results:

```
 record_id | match_criteria_1 | match_criteria_2 | match_criteria_3 | dollars | total_dollars
-----------+------------------+------------------+------------------+---------+---------------
         1 | A                | V                | F                |      10 |           210
         2 | A                | W                | G                |      20 |           210
         3 | B                | W                | H                |      30 |           210
         4 | B                | X                | I                |      40 |           210
         5 | C                | Y                | F                |      50 |           210
         6 | C                | Z                | J                |      60 |           210
         7 | M                | N                | O                |     100 |           210
(7 rows)
```

Comment: total_dollars should be 100 for Record 7 since it only matches with itself.